# What's this database format called and how to do it?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been searching around the site and couldn't find what I was looking for, so I'm creating my own topic on this. I've seen multiple PHP frameworks use this format in their respective MySQL database. I know WordPress (plugins, settings, roles etc.) and Pagekit uses it and it looks like this (this is from WordPress):

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

Sometimes it looks a lot more complex and contains a really long string of settings.

And a more simpler approach from PageKit:

```
{"title":"1","markdown":"1"}
```

Which looks a lot like JSON format, IMO.

How do I read this and how would I use this from the database in a PHP script when retrieving the data from a database.

I'm curious because I think it looks to be a proper way to store multiple settings in a database.

Comment: The second one seems JSON. The first one not quite. Either way, it's a poor and lazy way to store settings in a database. Actually, one should think twice before storing settings in a database at all.

Comment: The first is likely serialized data from PHP.  You can use unserialize($string) and print the output for a more readable format.

Comment: Even the JSON you find poor and lazy? How would you store settings for your app in the database if I may ask. #drmarvelous > Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: use json_decode to read this. And store the same as String.

Comment: It is perfectly normal to store an indeterminate number of settings/preferences in a JSON representation or serialized version in a table.  If the number of preferences is pre-set though, it may be more efficient to store them each as their own column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one looks like a serialised array. Second one is simply JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is not JSON. But, second one looks like JSON format. So, its like

```
{"Key1": "Value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

Same as something like MongoDB use to store DB in JSON format.